# Форма обратной связи после отправки ссылается на файл

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть форма обратной связи, там есть всякие `input` поля и ещё прикрепляется файл. Так вот, после отправки формы, если ещё раз нажать на ссылку "прикрепить файл" то подсвечивается выбранный ранее файл. Но если страницу обновить, то выбор по новой. И если форму отправить повторно, не прикрепляя файла, он прикрепиться снова. Как после отправки формы обнулить значение прикреплённого файла?

```
$('#form_values_file').val('');
```

не помогает

Answer (score 1):

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/clear-a-file-input/

**JQuery**

```
var input = $("#control");

function something_happens() {
    input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
};
```

Вызывать функцию на отправку формы и на `$( document ).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#form_values_file').trigger( 'reset' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать reset всей формы, обратившись к ней по её `id`. Пример для формы с `id` *"your_form_id"*:

```
$('#your_form_id')[0].reset();
```